# div positions are not being responsive css

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a single page application where I want divs to display one below the other. But on resizing the viewport to various screen sizes, the positioning is getting overlapped and leaving extra spaces in between. I have codepen example to explain the problem in a better way.

https://codepen.io/SaloniDesai/pen/zPBZJr

How to make the divs appear same for every screen size ?Do i need to shuffle the way I have created the layout of the page ?

```
<div id="headliner" class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h1>SearchGIFY app</h1>
          <p>search for any GIF you want!</p> 
        </div>
        <div id="search">
            <form>
                <input type="search" ng-model="vm.search.gif" value="" placeholder="type what you're looking for" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.performSearch()">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card">
                <img ng-repeat="g in vm.giphies" ng-src="{{g.images.original.url}}" height="{{g.images.fixed_height}}" title="{{g.title}}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron text-center" id="trendingBar">
            <h3>Trending gifs</h3>
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img ng-repeat="trending in vm.trendingGifs" ng-src="{{trending.images.original.url}}" height="{{trending.images.fixed_height.height}}" title="{{trending.title}}">
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your bootstrap structure isn't good, there isn't container, neither rows or col. 
Try this one:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="headliner col-md-12" class="jumbotron text-center">
      <h1>SearchGIFY app</h1>
      <p>search for any GIF you want!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="search">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-inline text-center col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" ng-model="vm.search.gif" value=""
                   placeholder="type what you're looking for"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.performSearch()">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <img ng-repeat="g in vm.giphies" ng-src="{{g.images.original.url}}" height="{{g.images.fixed_height}}"
           title="{{g.title}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center" id="trendingBar">
      <h3>Trending gifs</h3>
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-repeat="trending in vm.trendingGifs" ng-src="{{trending.images.original.url}}"
             height="{{trending.images.fixed_height.height}}" title="{{trending.title}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, you add a lot of absolute class with % height and width. You don't have to do that if you're using bootstrap, all the responsive stuff is handled by the bootstrap grid with col classes. Take a quick look at the grid bootstrap documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Here's the codepen working responsively with some modification : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOemgw ;)

Comment: Thanks i will try it! what if i don't want white spaces between every row?

Comment: The .jumbotron class has a margin-bottom: 30px, just override it